# Select sqldasource query from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I have a grid which has a dasource selected sqlDataSource2. I have not built any query in the datasource. I have a dropdownlist with two items and I would like to select the query from the dropdownlist and after selection of the query update the grid to show the result.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Query1();
}

 protected void Query1()
{
    //if (this.IsPostBack)
 {
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PMIcommConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = @"SELECT YEAR(custDecDate), SUM(valueXX), SUM(valueYY)
                                     FROM bids
                                    WHERE forBid ='"+ DropDownList3.SelectedValue +"'GROUP BY YEAR(custDecDate)'";
    SqlDataSource2.DataBind();
    RadGrid1.DataBind();
 }
}
```

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="PMIcommConnectionString" connectionString="Data
Source=WIN-72PL3253COR\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PMIcomm;Integrated
Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get an error "Connection string has not been initialized" on the last line. How can I make this working? Beside the error I am getting, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. Sorry for asking such simple thing, I am a selflearning beginner.

Comment: use var string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PMIcommConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

Comment: Can you show how you have specified your connectionstring in web.config?

Comment: @RKS I have updated my question with the connection string

Comment: @Nullbyte: You have specified this within <connectionString>. Just follow the answer provided by Neel. That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string is not in AppSettings.

What you're looking for is in:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PMIcommConnectionString"].ConnectionStri‌​ng;
```

Comment: I have update my question with the code as it is now after your answer. But I still have the same problem.

Comment: what exact error you are getting and at which step after the change @Nullbyte

Comment: hey btw I have just given the example I mean I have just noticed you have placed exact code in your code..just make neccessory changes instead of putting exact code @Nullbyte

Answer (score 1):

**Web.config:**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PMIcommConnectionString" connectionString="Data
    Source=WIN-72PL3253COR\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PMIcomm;Integrated
    Security=True"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

**Code Behind .cs:**

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PMIcommConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```